# TypeScript this keyword context error - undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-lambda

I have a aws lambda written in JS (TypeScript) which calls functions from different classes. I am getting **undefined** for the existingproducts variable even though it works fine when the REACT UI sends a call to the function. Below is my code using **this** keyword to reference the method of other class with current object in scope.

**Entry point for the lambda**

```
export const handler = async (upload: FileUpload, context: Context) => {
     .....code .....
     const parser = new ExcelValidator(new LookupService(), new ProductService());
     const status = await parser.performExistingUpcValidation(products as Product[], upload, workbook);
     return status
```

**PerformExisitingUPCValidation**

```
export class ExcelValidator {

    constructor(public lookupService: LookupService, public productService: ProductService) {

    }

    async performExistingUpcValidation(products: Product[], upload: FileUpload, workbook?: Workbook): Promise<FileStatus> {
       ...code...
       const existingProducts: any[] = await this.productService.getExistingProductsByUpcOrProductCode(productUpcs, productCodes);
       console.log("This is the exisitingProduct", existingProducts)
}
```

**ProductServiceClass**

```
export class ProductService {


    constructor() {
    }

    @Query(()=>[Product])
    async getExistingProductsByUpcOrProductCode(@Arg("upcs", ()=> [String]) upcs: string[], @Arg("productCodes", ()=> [String]) productCodes: string[]): Promise<Product[]> {
        console.log("I came here")
        let query = `SELECT * from table
            in (${upcs.join(",")})`;
        if(productCodes.length){
            query += ` OR "productCode" in ('${productCodes.join("','")}')`;
        }
        const results = await pool.snowflake?.execute(query);
        return results as Product[];
    }
```

After all the execution I am able to see

```
This is the exisitingProduct undefined
```

which means my execution does not reach the ProductServiceClass. Can someone point me to what is wrong or missing? Also any documentation/reference to read more will help alot.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion for you is review the item below:

```
const results = await pool.snowflake?.execute(query);
```

Are you confident that snowflake is not null, because you are accepting to be undefined with help of the question mark.

Comment: yes, that seems to be the issue, snowflake is undefined. I have defined the above interface as
export interface Pool {
    snowflake?: Snowflake;
}

export const pool: Pool = {
}